# Saga tools missing in QGIS

Tags: qgis, saga

First things first! I am using Ubuntu Mate on 15.04. I installed Qgis and SAGA via the http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu packages. So I use QGIS 2.12 and SAGA 2.1.4.

I wanted to use the cluster analysis for grid tool, available in the SAGA-toolbox and I couldn't find it. It should be under shapes->table but I checked and the entire table-tools are missing. Others might be missing too (Qgis is showing 235 SAGA-tools). The ones which are there are fully functionable.

In the official SAGA-programm the tool is visible though. So how can I port the missing tools into QGIS?

Comment: Possibly because the SAGA version is older? I'm on Lubuntu 14.04, QGIS 2.12.0, and SAGA 2.2.0, and the SAGA algorithms port just fine to QGIS. SAGA was installed independently before QGIS was. By the way, "Cluster Analysis for Grids" is under Imagery - Classification.

Comment: Oh my god! I am sorry! They actually translated the names for the tools now, I was used to the English names so much. I just changed the language back to English and there is the tool. Soory for taking up your time. However how do I update to SAGA 2.2?

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure that the name of the tool is not translated into your language! Otherwise this might be very confusing. Settings->Options->Locale, tick "override system locale" and use U.S. English.